# How to search for a specific file name based on only the string?

Tags: php

So I want to do a search for a file that only matches the string. For example, I put in tea, it shouldn't search for a file called "steam" since it has the string tea in it. It should only search for tea or tea party etc. Here is some code that I played with:

```
 foreach ($files as $file) {
     if (strpos($file, $string) !== false) {
         echo $file
     }
}
```

The above code is iterating through the files array (which has the files within the directory) and checking if the string matches with any instance that would have "tea" in it. What would I need to change so that it will only look for instances of the word tea?

Comment: `if (strtolower($file) == strtolower($string)) {` (for case-insensitive). for case-sensitive remove `strtolower()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `preg_match` with a regular expression

```
$word = 'tea';
$regex = "/\b{$word}\b/";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (preg_match($regex, $file)) {
        echo $file;
    }
}
```

This will only match if the word tea is anywhere in the file name as a separate word (`\b` in the regex is a word boundary). So steam is not a match.

Answer (score 0):

This will find any instance of the word - case-insensitive - whether on its own or delimited with a `-` or `_`. Example link included

```
<?php
// example code

function findFileByWord($word) {
    $files = array('steam.jpg', 'Tea-party.jpg', 'teambuilding.jpg', 'green_TEA_drinking.jpg', 'tea.jpg', 'the best tea.jpg');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $pieces = preg_split('/(\-|_| )/', explode(".",strtolower($file))[0]);
        if (in_array(strtolower($word), $pieces)) echo $file."\n";
    }
}

findFileByWord('tea');
```

Output:

```
Tea-party.jpg
green_TEA_drinking.jpg
tea.jpg
the best tea.jpg
```

Example: https://www.tehplayground.com/QTE9Ycw4JBXSi0n0